# variable leaking between subprocesses in bash

Tags: bash, variables, export, parent-child, handle-leak

Hi there everyone at stackoverflow I'm having an issue with a bash script running as a child with a variable conflict from my parent script. I have a subprocess that starts and pulls variables from the parent. What I have going on is that within each of those child processes that run simultaneously every second the varaibles crossover between children. for example UnitIP UnitPort and Unitname are all defined from and array but as the next child opens the other child also receives the changes made to unitip unitPort, etc... anyone have a solution for this problem? so let's say UnitIP=${IP[0]} child is opened with UnitIP=${IP[0]}, loop comes back around UnitIP=${IP[1]} second child opens with UnitIP=${IP[1]} and the first child also changes to UnitIP=${IP[1]} thank you for your time and help.

```
for (( c=0; c<=$id-1; c++ ))
do
t8=$t
export t=$t8
export UnitIP=${IP[$c]}
export UnitPort=${Port[$c]}
export UnitName=${Name[$c]}
export UnitActive=${Active[$c]}
subsprogram.sh &
done
```

Comment: Can you post an example of `subprogram.sh` which actually exhibits this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(untested) You could create a subshell for each child so they don't share the same <strike>parent</strike> environment:

```
for (( c=0; c<=$id-1; c++ ))
do
    t8=$t
    (
        export t=$t8
        export UnitIP=${IP[$c]}
        export UnitPort=${Port[$c]}
        export UnitName=${Name[$c]}
        export UnitActive=${Active[$c]}
        subsprogram.sh &
    ) 
done
```

Comment: I like that solution I'm gonna give it a try

Comment: I think technically they will share the same parent, but they won't share the environment of their common parent - said the pedantic old fool Setchell :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just set the variable for the one command:

```
UnitIP=xyz subprocess &
```

Comment: Actually originally I had subprocess $c & and then ip, port, name and active were defined in the subprocess but the value of $c still shifted continuously inside of my subprocess as the next subprocess opened

Comment: Or put them all in a subshell like this ()